# Monitor kafka under Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: apache-kafka, grafana, prometheus

I wish to monitor Kafka with Prometheus and Grafana.

I have downloaded kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0

```
 cd kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0
```

and downloaded :

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.6/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.6.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/master/example_configs/kafka-0-8-2.yml
```

Started Zookeeper using :

```
nohup bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties >> zookeeper.log &
KAFKA_OPTS="$KAFKA_OPTS -javaagent:$PWD/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.6.jar=7071:$PWD/kafka-0-8-2.yml"
```

Started kafka using :

```
nohup bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties >> kafka.log &
```

**logs of zookeeper :**

```
INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15b18c79a630075 type:create cxid:0x81f216 zxid:0x2b87c2 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error 
Path:/consumers/logstash/ids/logstash_wavescore-staging-1490769576466-92cd1041 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/logstash/ids/logstash_wavescore-staging-149076
9576466-92cd1041 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15b18c79a630075 type:create cxid:0x81f219 zxid:0x2b87c3 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error 
Path:/consumers/logstash/ids/logstash_wavescore-staging-1490769576466-92cd1041 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/logstash/ids/logstash_wavescore-staging-149076
9576466-92cd1041 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15b18c79a630075 type:create cxid:0x81f21c zxid:0x2b87c4 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error 
Path:/consumers/logstash/ids/logstash_wavescore-staging-1490769576466-92cd1041 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/logstash/ids/logstash_wavescore-staging-149076
9576466-92cd1041 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

**logs of kafka :**

```
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,36] in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataM
anager)
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading offsets and group metadata from [__consumer_offsets,39] (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,39] in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataM
anager)
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading offsets and group metadata from [__consumer_offsets,42] (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,42] in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataM
anager)
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading offsets and group metadata from [__consumer_offsets,45] (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,45] in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataM
anager)
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading offsets and group metadata from [__consumer_offsets,48] (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,48] in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataM
anager)
INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager
```

When i check the `netstat` in the server , there is no  port 7071 was opened and `curl localhost:7071 was resulted curl: (7) couldn't connect to host .`

Reference Link :
 https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-kafka-with-prometheus/
 in this link they were using kafka version :  kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.tgz

I have downloaded  : kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0

Answer (score 1):

It might be the wrong variable. I have managed to monitor my kafka broker with jolokia agent and metricbeat but it should be the same. Here is the script i am using to start the broker:

```
export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS=-javaagent:/opt/kafka/jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar=port=8778,host=localhost
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon config/server_cluster.properties
```

Hope it can help.

NB: Make sure the owner of the agent jar is the same than the user you use to launch the broker.